# XAML - PostAsync sending null data to database

Tags: c#, uwp, dotnet-httpclient

I've been trying to get a grasp on C#/.NET and UWP applications. At the moment I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/crud-operations-in-uwa-using-web-api/) to complete CRUD operations against my database. So far so good, but when I come to the part where I want to create I run into som troubles. The code below is where I create a new object and try to post it to the database. Piece in this context is a book.

```
var newPiece = new Piece
{
    PieceTitle = Title.Text,
    PieceAuthor = Author.Text,
    PieceIsbn = Isbn.Text,
    PieceDescription = Description.Text
};

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newPiece);

    Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var data = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(
            new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["value"] = content
            });
        await client.PostAsync(App.BaseUri, data);
    });

    task.Wait();
}
```

The problem here is that because I am using both `HttpClient()` and `HttpFormUrlEncodedContent()` VS is telling me that `HttpClient()` is "an ambiguous reference" and that I need to specify if it belongs to `System.Net.Http;` or `Windows.Web.Http;`. If I choose `System.Net.Http` then it tells me that Argument 1 in `PostAsync()` "*cannot be converted from 'System.Uri' to 'string'*", and that Argument 2 "*cannot convert from 'Windows.Web.Http.HttpFormUrlEncodedContent' to 'System.Net.Http.HttpContent'*"

If I try letting `HttpClient()` use `Windows.Web.Http;` then it doesn't give me any errors while compiling, but after the object has been created and posted it displays as *null* in my tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Net.Http` name space has `FormUrlEncodedContent`. You can use that.

```
var newPiece = new Piece
{
    PieceTitle = Title.Text,
    PieceAuthor = Author.Text,
    PieceIsbn = Isbn.Text,
    PieceDescription = Description.Text
};

using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient()) {
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newPiece);            
    var content = new System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent(
        new Dictionary<string, string> {
            ["value"] = json
        });
    await client.PostAsync(App.BaseUri, content);           
}
```

Should also try to avoid mixing async and blocking calls like `.Wait()` or `.Result` as they can lead to deadlocks.

It was also indicated that the data when received is null. This could be an indication that the format being used does not match the expected format.

Try using a different format. For example the following sends JSON content.

```
using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient()) {
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newPiece);            
    var content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    await client.PostAsync(App.BaseUri, content);           
}
```

Comment: VS is not giving me the option to use `System.Net.Http` on `FormUrlEncodedContent`. And if I try to force it with `System.Net.Http.HttpFormUrlEncodedContent` it still doesn't compile. It tells me I can "Generate class 'HttpFormUrlEncodedContent' in new file".

Comment: Nevermind. I tried setting it up like you did, and it removes the errors I had. However it now tells me that the `Button_Click` needs to be Async so it now reads `private async void Button_Click` but it still gives me *null* on the data...

Comment: @PQuix show the definition of the target action/endpoint the data is being sent to.

Comment: show the code when you say `it still gives me null on the data`

Comment: Well, the registration seems to go through just fine, but if I open my tables then they just display *null* in every row. And in my `ListView` that contains all the objects, it creates rows for the created objects, but they're empty, and if I select them I get "Value cannot be null". So I'm not sure what code you're referring to.

Comment: @PQuix are you sure the service you are calling required form data and not JSON?

Comment: Seems like you were onto something. Got it working with this:


`var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newPiece);
                var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
                byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                var result = client.PostAsync(App.BaseUri, byteContent).Result;`